# How do i save Image(Jpg,Jpeg) file in excel for each cell

Tags: vba, excel, jpeg

I want to attach a different image for different cells. SO far I am doing by attach the image via ("link"). I am facing some problem that whenever I try to send file I have to send the corrsponding path file . But sometimes its annoying that folders will be erased or moved . Can anyone give me an valuable suggestions, that I can save all my image in the file(excel) , whereas I can send only the excel sheet, when some one click the cell , corrosponding image boot from the cell(excel).

Is it possiible in excel, if it so please give me the instruction.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to save your file in older format, for example in Excel 97-2003. By default newer formats keep links, not pictures.

If you insert pictures via a macro, use something like the following:

```
 Cells(1,1).AddPicture(FileName:="C:\1.jpg", SaveWithDocument:=True)
```

If you are using "insert picture" method via the insert tab in excel, within "insert picture" window you can choose "insert" at the bottom of the window. i'm not too sure how exactly it is called in English, but my translation is pretty close to what it might be.

[image]